# What does 전원 위치로! and 서둘러! mean?

Tags: meaning

I was watching a movie and there are two muffled sentences that can't be heard clearly, but there are Korean subtitles. Could you please tell me what these might mean? Thanks!

Context: A ship is sinking and people are panicking.

전원 위처로! and 서튤레!

[image: Screenshot of the first subtitle]

[image: Screenshot of the second subtitle]

Answer (score 10):

전원 위치로! = Everybody back to position! (Sounds very military.)

서둘러! = Hurry up!

Answer (score 1):

1. Everyone(전원) move to the designated spot!(위치로!)
2. Hurry up!(서둘러!)